# Error: The "extra.eas.projectId" field is missing from your app config

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

I am currently working on a cross-platform application using React Native and Expo. Right now, I am attempting to submit the iOS version of the app to the App Store. I have followed the instructions [here](https://docs.expo.dev/build/setup/) closely; however, every time I attempt to run `eas build` and select `iOS` as the intended platform, my build fails.

The given reason for my build failing is that "The "extra.eas.projectId" field is missing from your app config." However, this is simply not the case: my `app.json` file clearly [image: contains this field]. Another developer on my team has gotten Android builds to work, which is especially curious. Has anyone else run into this issue or a similar issue?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and I had also multiple developers working on the same project. One of them had added the app.json to the .gitignore. I removed it and it worked like a charm.